# Calling two php files on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have coded a form that gets 2 kinds of values from the user, one for promo details and the other asks for a photo (the photo is optional). I need to get the photo to be uploaded in a folder and have it slideshowed. My question is how do I send the photo to the folder and insert the promo details to the database and what slideshow tool should I use that just picks out random images on a folder?  here is my code for the form that asks the user input and photo:

```
<FORM action="insertPromo.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtPromoName">Promo Title:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" id="divCmbService"">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtPromoName" id="txtPromoName" placeholder="Promo Name">
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="cmbService">Service to discount:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                            <select id="cmbService" name="cmbService" class="form-control" onchange="showService(this.value)">
                                    <option value="0">- Select One -</option>
                        <?php                                       
                            $dbHost = "localhost";
                            $dbUser = "mdchadmin";
                            $dbPass = "123456";
                            $dbName = "mdch_new";

                            $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
                                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                                } 
                                $sql = "SELECT service_id, service_name FROM services";
                                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    echo "<option value=\"{$row['service_id']}\">{$row['service_name']}</option>";
                                                }
                                }                                       
                                $conn->close();                                         
                            ?>
                            </select>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtPresyo">Input Promo Cost:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" id="divCmbService"">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtPresyo" id="txtPresyo" placeholder="0.00">
                    </div>
            </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtValidFrom">Valid From:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control login-field" type="date" id="txtValidFrom" name="txtValidFrom" size=17>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtValidUntil">Valid Until:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control login-field" type="date" id="txtValidUntil" name="txtValidUntil" size=17>
                        </div>
                </div>
                        <?php echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="txtServiceName"> Promo photo upload:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10" id="divCmbService"">
                        <INPUT NAME="promo" TYPE="file" enctype = "multipart/form-data">                        
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">    
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <INPUT TYPE="submit" class="btn btn-default" VALUE="Add Promo">
                </div>
            </div>  


            </FORM>
```

Here is my code for the file that sends the data to the database:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include('session.php');
if (false==$_SESSION['isAdmin']){ 
    header("Location:index.php");
    die();      
}
?>
<html lang="en">

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
            <?php
            include('nav_admin.php');
            ?>
        <div id="page-wrapper"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Insert a new Promo</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="container">
                        <?php           


                                try{
                                            $dbHost = "localhost";
                                            $dbUser = "mdchadmin";
                                            $dbPass = "123456";
                                            $dbName = "mdch_new";

                                            $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
                                            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                                                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                                            } 

                                            // Escape user inputs for security
                                            $promoTitle= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtPromoName']);
                                            $serviceID = $_POST['cmbService'];
                                            $discountedCost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtPresyo']);
                                                date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');
                                                $validFrom = $_POST['txtValidFrom'];
                                                $validUntil = $_POST['txtValidUntil'];
                                                $dateFrom = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($validFrom));
                                                $dateUntil= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($validUntil));
                                            //$total_payment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtTotalPayment']);

                                            // attempt insert query execution
                                            $sql = "INSERT INTO PROMOS (PROMO_NAME, SERVICE_ID, DISCOUNTED_PRICE, VALID_FROM, VALID_UNTIL) VALUES ('$promoTitle', $serviceID, $discountedCost, '$dateFrom', '$dateUntil')";
                                            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                                                echo "Promo ";ECHO $promoTitle; echo " created. The promo is valid from "; echo $dateFrom; echo " until "; echo $dateUntil;

                                            } else {
                                                echo "Cannot insert the promo. Please fill up all of the fields.";
                                            }

                                            // close connection
                                            $conn->close();




                                }catch (Exception $e) {
                                            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                                        }

                        ?>  
                                <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="addPromo.php" method="post">
                                <?php echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";?>                    
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <INPUT TYPE="submit" class="btn btn-default" VALUE="Back to Add Promo Page">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have googled how to upload the pic and it works for me, but I dont know how I can do the photo upload and the insertion of data to the db simultaneously.

Comment: you don't need to send it to two scripts.  Make both pieces part of the same script.  If you already have both scripts you can use an include for one of them

Comment: ok, I will try to do what you suggested. How then would I randomly slideshow the images in the folder where the images are being uploaded?

Comment: For a slideshow, jquery should be fine, as you suggest

Comment: btw, `<INPUT NAME="promo" TYPE="file" enctype = "multipart/form-data">` remove `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` from your input. It belongs in `<form>`

Comment: I can now do both php files by using something like this:


<?php
  include('insertPromo.php');
  include('upload.php');
?>

Can you guys help me on how to randomly slideshow the photos from a folder? what tool should I use or how would I make my own slider?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  include('insertPromo.php');//this writes to the db
  include('upload.php'); //this uploads the photo
?>
```

then make the form action="promoIncluder.php" where promo includer contains the code above